# Google Chrome 54.0.2840.71 slow rendering speed

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I have an HTML5 game made with the [Phaser](http://phaser.io/) game engine. Before about a week, I was getting 60fps (the maximum) out of it on Chrome. However, since the latest [update](http://portableapps.com/news/2016-10-24--google-chrome-portable-54.0.2840.71-released) I'm getting an average of 28fps. The engine hasn't changed, as well as the game's code. Meanwhile in Firefox, I still get 60. I can get 60 in Chrome only if I make the browser window smaller, so that the canvas is smaller and there's less stuff to render.

Does anyone know what's the issue?